# Storing nested objects in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 3 level nested object something like below, I want to index these objects in elastic search. Requirement here is users will write a search query keywords like "keyword1 keyword2 ..." and I want to return objects that has all of these keywords in it (at any level i.e. AND operation).

```
   [  
   {  
      "country":[  
         {  
            "name":"India",
            "ext_code":"91",
            "states":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Karnataka",
                  "ext_code":"04",
                  "cities":[  
                     {  
                        "name":"Bangalore",
                        "ext_code":"080"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Currently, I store them in nested format using the following mapping:

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "doc":{
            "properties":{
                "name": {"type":"text"},
                "ext_code": {"type":"text"}
                "state" {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {"type":"text"},
                        "ext_code": {"type":"text"}
                        "city" {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {"type":"text"}
                                "ext_code": {"type":"text"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And while searching, I pass elastic search a nested query to search on all levels like below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "keyword1 keyword2 ...",
                        "fields": ['name'] 
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": 'state',
                        "query": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "keyword1 keyword2 ...",
                                "fields": ['state.name']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": 'state.city',
                        "query": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "keyword1 keyword2 ...",
                                "fields": ['state.city.name']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When sending multiple tokens to search, it applies an OR operation returning documents containing any of the search tokens.

Is there a way to configure Elastic Search to perform an AND operation for multiple tokens in search query?

Comment: Hi Lokesh, what is technically possible will always receive a solution, but sometimes you think that some solutions are harder if you don't know the purpose of what you are trying to accomplish, why did you choose nested types for this?

Comment: U mean I could have stored it as a flat structure?

Comment: yep, but offcourse, all depends on the types of queries you want to run, one ES engineer once told me, nested types result eventually optimized (cpu & memory, hence costs) by converting the structure to flat and adding a little bit of work on the client side.

Comment: Is there any impact on analysis (using Kibana) by flattening out the data?

Comment: huge, kibana is designed for a "time-series first" data schema, flat is king in time-series, so yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to index all the values of the `name` fields inside a custom [`all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields). First define your index and mappings like this:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "all": {                 <-- all field that will contain all values
          "type": "text"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "all"       <-- copy value to all field
        },
        "ext_code": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "copy_to": "all"       <-- copy value to all field
            },
            "ext_code": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "city": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "copy_to": "all"       <-- copy value to all field
                },
                "ext_code": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then index your documents:

```
POST index/doc
{
  "name": "India",
  "ext_code": "91",
  "state": [
    {
      "name": "Karnataka",
      "ext_code": "04",
      "city": [
        {
          "name": "Bangalore",
          "ext_code": "080"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, using a simple match query, you can search for any value anywhere in the document:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "all": {
              "query": "bangalore india",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                        "query": "keyword1 keyword2 ...",
                        "fields": ['name'] ,
                        "default_operator": "and"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": 'state',
                        "query": {
                            "simple_query_string": {
                                "query": "keyword1 keyword2 ...",
                                "fields": ['state.name'],
                                "default_operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": 'state.city',
                        "query": {
                            "simple_query_string": {
                                "query": "keyword1 keyword2 ...",
                                "fields": ['state.city.name'],
                                "default_operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think multi_match is good for this requirement. Simple query string or query string query is better suited for this purpose.

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html